# How to allow direct URL access to my website through .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, permissions

So whenever I try to access directories on my website, I am directed to a 403 Forbidden page. Here is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/highmo2/public_html

# xmlrpc Protection
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
Redirect 301 /xmlrpc.php http://127.0.0.1
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything I could add to this file, to allow direct URL access?

Comment: `Options +Indexes` ?

Comment: @CD001 Doing that gives me a 500 Internal Server Error on all pages. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Did you do it before I moved the `+` sign? Had it in the wrong place initially :\